# How do I put a textbox entry into while loop? C#

Tags: c#, textbox, while-loop

This is essentially what I am trying to do. I want to allow someone to enter a number on how many times they want to run a specific program. What I can't figure out is how to change the number 10 into (textBox1.Text). If you have a better way please let me know. I am very new to programming.

```
int counter = 1;
while ( counter <= 10 )
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are starting, so I would suggest to use a plain old for loop instead of a while here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows how to take the user-supplied input and ***safely*** convert it to an integer (System.Int32) and use it in your counter.

```
int counter = 1;
int UserSuppliedNumber = 0;

// use Int32.TryParse, assuming the user may enter a non-integer value in the textbox.  
// Never trust user input.
if(System.Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out UserSuppliedNumber)
{
   while ( counter <= UserSuppliedNumber)
   {
       Process.Start("notepad.exe");
       counter = counter + 1;  // Could also be written as counter++ or counter += 1 to shorten the code
   }
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Invalid number entered.  Please enter a valid integer (whole number).");
}
```

Comment: No problem.  We were all new once.  I wish this site had been around when I was new.

Answer (score 2):

Try `System.Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out counterMax)` ([Docs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)) to convert a string to a number.

This will return a true if the conversion succeeded or a false if it failed (i.e., the user entered something that isn't an integer)

Comment: If you suggested TryParse instead it would be better

Comment: That's a good point, I'll change it. My first thought was that `Int32.Parse()` fits better into a loop like that, but `TryParse` is better.

Answer (score 2):

textBox1.Text will return a string.  You need to convert it into an int and since it's taking user input, you'll want to do so safely:

```
int max;
Int32.TryParse(value, out max);
if (max)
{
    while ( counter <= max ) {}
}
else
{
    //Error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use MaskedTextBox control to take input from user, which will help us to ensure that only numbers will supplied. It will not bound us for `TryParse` functionality.

Set mask like this: (can use "Property Window")

```
MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "00000";   // will support upto 5 digit numbers
```

then use like this:

```
int finalRange = int.Parse(MaskedTextBox1.Text);
int counter = 1;
while ( counter <= finalRange )
{
    Process.Start("notepad.exe");
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Try Catch body ,like this function

```
bool ErrorTextBox(Control C)
    {
        try
        {
            Convert.ToInt32(C.Text);
            return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

and use